# Filter an array with elements by first letter of each word

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, typescript2.0

I have this code :

```
return !this.form.get('skills').value.map(item => item.id).includes(skill.id) &&
            (value === null || skill.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase()));
```

I have this liste :

```
Artist
Armagedon
Commandos Artist
Refactor
Gol Jumir Afart
Armony
```

If I write : `A` : I get the liste :

```
Artist
Armagedon
Armony
```

But I want to get and items : `Commandos Artist` and `Gol Jumir Afart`.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: You better use regex.

Comment: Provide some more detals of json. In above ligic you mentiond id. But given json it not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Regexp in order to filter your values. We are going to look for every words starting by your letter.

```js
const myFilter = 'A';

const regex = new RegExp(`(^${myFilter}.*)|( ${myFilter}.*)`, 'i');

const filtered = [
  'Artist',
  'Armagedon',
  'Commandos Artist',
  'Commandos Artist Paul',
  'Refactor',
  'Gol Jumir Afart',
  'armony',
].filter(x => regex.test(x));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: this solutions works only for sensitive cas, is possible to do on insensitive ?

Comment: @frint Yes by adding the flag `i` to the regexp. I've edited the snippet